Generate a 60 Hz signal to emulate a current transformer using a Raspberry Pi
I am attempting to use a Raspberry Pi zero 2 W to emulate the signal from the leads (secondary winding) of a current transformer.  The current transformer whose signal I would like to emulate is a CR Magnetics CR8348-2500-N used to measure the current drawn by a house air conditioner unit in the US, 60Hz in the 15-30 A range. The emulated signal will be sent to a measurement device that normally handles the signal from an actual CT. I am currently using an MCP4822 DAC to create a 60 Hz voltage signal.  I believe will need to remove the DC component and to amplify the DAC's signal so that I can supply up to 20 mA RMS current.  I am looking for a sanity check on my approach and for ideas for the best way for me to condition/amplify my signal to achieve my goal.
EDIT:
The device under test reports RMS current and voltage, and frequency, and requires the CT I mentioned above as input.  I believe (by inspecting the board) that the device under test internally uses an Atmel M90E26.  We use the device in the field to measure a variety of different AC loads (e.g., Air conditioners, water heaters, irrigation pumps), which will of course have unique current signatures. For this test, I do not need to model the unique current signature of any one of these loads, but I need the device under test to detect an AC current at a magnitude equivalent to real CT measuring a 15 - 30A load (a pure resistive load is fine, PF=1.0 is fine) and report its RMS value.

is there a reason not to do this with a commercial off the shelf sound card on about any computer (including a raspberry pi)? The DAC bitdepths of sound hardware are impressive, and at least for not-totally-cheaped-out audio hardware, 60 Hz should still be doable (and you can simulate harmonics easily)

A soundcard could make the signal, but the swing and drive won't be enough (they want 7.5V RMS at least, and a soundcard can make only 1 or 2V RMS. Not enough. That said, the buffer I show below could work with a line input, with some gain fiddling.

Raspberry pi's internal PWM based audio output (3.5mm socket) probably has enough precision.

What does the true current signal shape look like. It may not be anything like a sinewave or whatever you have assumed it to be.

@Andyaka The true current signal is a sine wave at 60Hz. It is simply a scaled down version of whatever load it is measuring, so in my case, if the measured current is 10A RMS, the CT signal is 10/2510 = 4mA RMS. I have verified this with a scope. More specifically, I clipped the CT on the hot leg of the power cord supplying a 4A industrial light, attached the CT leads across a 100 Ohm resistor, and observed the voltage with an oscilloscope.

That is not a representative test in any way at all.

@Andyaka Sorry. I'd be glad for some pointers, then, on how to do it.  I thought it was.

You need to measure the current of the actual load because it may not be very sinusoidal at all and, that could disrupt what you hope to achieve by faking a real signal with a sinewave.

That's fair.  We use exactly this setup (real CT measuring the current on a light) as a test rig, and our device under test handles that signal acceptably.  For that reason I am considering it reasonable to measure, and replicate, the CT signal in that scenario.

An incandescent light will be a resistive load with a unity power factor, and a sine current waveform. An A/C unit will have an inductive load (so non-unity power factor) and likely a non-sine current too: it will have harmonics.

Need more info about your requirements. Is the goal to fool one power on/off sensor, once? To test arbitrary CT measuring devices? To check linearity, RMS calculation accuracy, sensitivity to harmonics?. For example you may find that applying 3.3 V DC to the input will work just fine to trigger a "something is drawing current" sensor.

Updated the question with more info re requirements.

The current transformer isn't grounded to anything, so we'll need to make an assumption that whatever is processing is dealing with biasing. Also, it's a differential signal from the CT.
The coil transformer's datasheet lists its characteristics as follows:

Max voltage output: 7.5Vrms
DC resistance (DCR): 138 ohms

So we want to model a differential signal that floating, yet models the transformer voltage and DCR. A basic idea would be:

use 2 high-current op-amp buffers, one inverting and one non-inverting, driven by 1 DAC
series resistors on the buffers to model DCR
AC-couple the op-amp outputs to model the floating coil

Here's a possible solution (simulate it here):

Design notes:

Gain is adjusted to give up to 8.7Vrms to an open circuit (the transformer specifies 7.5Vrms) with a 0-5V input sine wave. You can adjust this if your Pi's DAC/ADC hat has less swing than that.
The op-amps run on +12V single-ended.
The 68 ohm resistors model coil DCR (138 ohms/2, roughly). When connected to your load, they will form a voltage divider.
The capacitors represent the floating coil.
TI has some suggestions for high-current buffers: https://www.ti.com/lit/ab/sboa568/sboa568.pdf?ts=1730230983570

Another possibility for the buffers is to use a pair of speaker driver ICs like the LM386 They can handle an 8 ohm load with no issues, and can be wired up basically like an op-amp.
If your goal is to compute power and energy consumption you will also need to measure voltage so that you can compute instantaneous power, power factor and so forth. You could use the second DAC to model the voltage, and experiment with non-ideal waveforms and power factors.

1M is way too high,  120 ohms is about the highest they can use, also it's possible that one end of the transformer is grounded.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні I agree; I believe 120 ohms is about right for the "burden resistor" that I believe is likely being used by device under test to read the CT.  I think I can measure this with a real CT attached to the test device (but I have not yet done so).

@hacktastical What would you recommend for the 12V supply in your design?  I was hoping to be able to use the pi's power pins, but I can pivot on that preference if needed.

The reason I had 1M in the sim was to show its open-circuit voltage. It will be lower with a load, due to modeling the DCR, just like the actual coil.

The problem with using the Pi’s power pins is that there isn’t enough voltage to get the needed swing from the amp. You could use a boost module to make that, or use a separate power supply.

If I measured right, the equivalent resistance of the circuit that measures the CT signal is about 5 ohms.

How would I adjust the gain in software using your dual op amp design?  I would like to model different size loads and have them be software configurable.  I can of course adjust the DAC signal's amplitude, but the size of the resistors assumes a fixed DAC signal amplitude, correct?

I sized the gain to be 2.5, assuming a max 5V swing at the DAC. The actual swing is 0~2.048 or 0~4.096V. If you increase the gain to 2.8 then you will get the full range again.

Ok it's a 1:2510 transformer so you need to make 12mA at up-to 7.5VRMS, so about 100mW of audio power.
As you don't know how the receiving end is wired you probably need transformer isolation.
I'd go with a small pc speaker amplifier (desktop pc speakers) driving an 1:4 step-up audio transformer, instead of the 8 ohm speaker and if it was a regular raspberry pi use the raspberry pi's audio output as the signal source.
since you have a pi zero you'll build an analogue output, but seeing at these current-transformers are only goot to 2khz, you can probably get by with a PWM at a slow-ish rate (like 8kKz) and still make a convincing-enough sine wave.  I don't know what PWM hardware the pi zero has, if it doesn't have enough PWM outputs it's possible that software based PWM could work,  else you'll need external outputs.
I2S codecs would be massive overkill... but you need to fiigure out what performance you need.
What gain to set is a mystery it depends on what resistor the receiver is using, but for 120 Ohms you want about 6V RMS at the output (so about 9V peak-to-peak) so about 2.25V peak to peak into the transformer.  (if a 1:4 transformer)

Thanks.  A few clarifications.  First, ideally I would like to be able to emulate at least 2, and possibly 4, independent CT signals from one raspberry pi.  Second, the pi zero doesn't have an audio output (but I believe can send audio signal some other ways, GPIO pins or HDMI for example).  Third, if I do use an approach like this, could you point me at how to program the pi to send the signal to the audio out?  And lastly, could you point me toward some parts that could work for the amplifier/transformer combo?  I assume the transformer you mention would isolate the signal as you recommend?

how to program the pi is off topic here, as are shopping questions.

Possibly the simplest way would be to connect the RPi via HDMI to a monitor with an audio output jack. The monitor will output HDMI audio to the jack via its integrated DAC. So that's done for you. Should cost about $100 for the monitor plus the cost of the cable(s).
Connect the audio jack / headphone output from the monitor to an audio amp and drive current through a small resistor. No need for DACs etc - off the shelf hardware would solve all of that. Generating a steady 60Hz sine wave via the RPi audio device is very simple.
This is one of those things that you could have up and running with just 30-60 minutes of effort. If you already have a loud audio setup for gaming etc. it may be zero effort, just some wiring.
